# Alternative for Gadwin Print Screen

Tags: linux, snapshot

does anyone know a good alternative for [Gadwin Print Screen](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/)?
I'm using Linux, but couldn't find a download version for it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not programming. I'm not sure which StackExchange site might be used to ask for software recommendations. Possibly http://superuser.com

Comment: At any rate you should also give more information on your Linux: distribution and environment (Gnome, KDE, other).

Answer (score 1):

I found shutter to be a good replacement for gadwin. It supports taking screenshots of a rectangular section on your desktop, which is a feature that I use a lot.

Website - http://shutter-project.org/

Download for ubuntu - https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/

Answer (score 0):

scrot is a command line program to that takes a screenshot of the x11 display and saves it to a file, you could probably find it in your distro's repositories or compile it from source: http://linuxbrit.co.uk/downloads/scrot-0.8.tar.gz

Scrot also has interactive window selection, which is a plus